# How to limit jinja2 logic?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'd like to use jinja2 for rendering strings like `"Value is {{ obj.value }}"`.

I only want to allow substituting template variables = the `{{ }}` syntax.

I do not want to allow any logic whatsoever = the `{% %}` syntax.

1. How do I make jinja2 rendering "less powerful" to achieve this?
2. Security concerns? Note that while these templates are to be input by the user, the rendered output will be rendered via jinja2 **again**, as part of an HTML template. So characters like `<` and `>` **will be escaped** before becoming HTML as sent to the browser.

Comment: An easy way is to use a regex search before the template is saved.